# How to run countdown timer process & other process parallelly in jframe form in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, logic

I am developing a quiz game where user have to answer within time. There i am showing a countdown timer in jframe form with the questions. So i need a jframe form where countdown timing & quiz questions process parallelly.
If I use multi thread how I stop a thread after another thread have stopped?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please share your code or risk having your question deleted.

Comment: [How to use Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) - You really only need one "thread" and a Swing `Timer` will provide you with all the functionality you need